# "I need to" list items open in new window?

Tags: hyperlink

I setup a "I Need To" dropdown that is hooked up to a Custom List with three columns: Title, Hyperlink, and Multichoice. The Hyperlink column holds my external links, and the multichoice is just a multichoice column with "yes" or "no" choices. All "Yes" items are viewed in the dropdown.

Is there a way for users to click on "I need to" dropdown items and have them open in new tabs or windows? Everything I've researched on how links can open in new tabs or windows involves HTML. Is there something I can add to the URL to signal the browser to open the link in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

`target="_blank"` in a href link should open a new window.

Or you could say: `javascript:OpenPopUpPage('yourUrl')`
You can put this in a href or in a function chain as:

```
function onDropChange(e) {
    // do something
    if(!!URL) // URL == true basicly
        OpenPopUpPage(URL);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But how do you insert an HTML href link into a SharePoint list?

Comment: depends on the list. usually you could add a script Webpart and override the onclick. Would need a more detailed Background about your list.
**In General get all list items ankers then set the href to**  `onclick='javascript:onDropChange(url)'` Dynamicly